# Converting a Fixed-Effect Model to Mixed-Effect Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model

I am studying the relationship between an experiment's predictors and its design matrix. For this particular question, I am curious how I can convert a design matrix developed for a Fixed Effect model into the two design matrices (Fixed + Random) of a Mixed Effect model.

---

The example experiment I made has 3 predictors:

- A :: [ Categorical, Unordered, 2 Levels ] --> (1, 2)
- B :: [ Categorical, Unordered, 4 Levels ] --> (1, 2, 3, 4)
- C :: [ Categorical, Unordered, 2 Levels ] --> (1, 2)

---

For now, I am assuming that all three predictors are Fixed Effect.

- A --> Fixed
- B --> Fixed
- C --> Fixed

---

An example data set containing 8 measurements (but only showing the predictor information, not the measured responses) for this example experiment can be written in table format:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

---

This particular experiment is a so-called "Split Plot" experiment, because predictor B's levels are nested within predictor A's levels, and predictor C's levels are crossed with predictor B's levels. These relationships can be shown via contingency tables.

*Contingency Table Between A and B (each x is a data point in the experiment, corresponding to one row in the table above):*

|  | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **B1** | x x |  |
| **B2** | x x |  |
| **B3** |  | x x |
| **B4** |  | x x |

*Contingency Table Between B and C:*

|  | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **B1** | x | x |
| **B2** | x | x |
| **B3** | x | x |
| **B4** | x | x |

*Contingency Table Between A and C:*

|  | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **C1** | x x | x x |
| **C2** | x x | x x |

---

After several attempts, I came up with a design matrix (using dummy coding) for this Fixed Effect experiment that I believe captures the idea of what a "Split Plot" experiment is.

The Fixed Effect design matrix contains columns for the simple effects of both predictor A and predictor C, as well the interactions of predictor B with predictor C.

The three BC interaction columns is what incorporates the idea that the effect of predictor C's Level 2 might change depending on what level of B it occurs within.

The design matrix is:

| I | A2 | C2 | B2C2 | B3C2 | B4C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

And the corresponding Fixed Effect model would be:

```
[I, A2, C2, B2C2, B3C2, B4C2] * [FE-Coefs] = Y
```

---

Now on to my question...

Usually in a Split Plot design the nested predictor (predictor B in this example) is modeled as a Random Effect, not a Fixed Effect.

In that case, the predictor information is the same, but predictor B will simply be thought of, and modeled as, a Random Effect:

- A --> Fixed
- B --> Random
- C --> Fixed

---

My question is:

Is there a simple way to split the design matrix described for the Fixed Effect experiment into the two design matrices (Fixed + Random) for the Mixed Effect experiment?

In other words, can I simply move the three columns of BC interactions into a new matrix exactly as they are coded, and then run a Mixed model with those design matrices?

The Mixed Effect model would then have the following separation of design matrix columns:

```
[I, A2, C2] * [FE-Coefs]  +  [B2C2, B3C2, B4C2] * [RE-Coefs] = Y
```

Comment: A split-plot design is determined based on how treatments (factor level combinations) are assigned to experimental units. Are you actually using this design?  If you are, in fact, randomly assigning a factor level combination to each unit and simply running a subset of all runs in a full factorial experiment, then you don't need to worry about random effects.

Comment: Also, you say "Usually in a Split Plot design the nested predictor (predictor B in this example) is modeled as a Random Effect, not a Fixed Effect". But actually, predictor B would be treated as fixed and predictor A would be effectively treated as both random and fixed. See, e.g., [this link](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~zhanghao/STAT514/Lecture_Notes/LectureNotes20-Split-plot-Designs-.html#:~:text=A%20split%2Dplot%20design%20is,randomly%20assigned%20to%20split%2Dplots.)

Comment: It's not a real experiment, however its true I did forget to include a theoretical randomization scheme. For the purposes of this example, I can imagine that I randomized according to standard Split Plot theory. For this example, I believe predictor B levels are called "Main Plots", to which the hard-to-change factor (predictor A) is randomly applied. Then, within each level of B, the easy-to-change factor (predictor C) is randomly applied.

Comment: My understanding of Split Plot design (although limited!) is that the Main Plots are typically treated as the levels of a Random Effect factor, but maybe I do not understand the Split Plot design theory. The Purdue link to Split Plot model math is for ANOVA technique, but I don't know if the ANOVA model and the Linear model have identical model terms (?) Additionally, is it possible that the ANOVA model is implicitly creating a random effects model? The reason I ask is that I could not include the predictor B main effects columns in the design matrix due to collinearity